# Calculate the difference between two times on two different days

Tags: c, time, difference

I am trying to determine the time difference between two times, which i represent as unsigned integers (in a sturct) as follows:

```
unsigned int day;
unsigned int month;
unsigned int year;

unsigned int hour;
unsigned int mins;
unsigned int seconds;
```

i can work out the time difference in minutes between two times that occur on the same day easily enough using: This isn't my exact code, this is just the logic behind it.

```
time1 = hours*3600 + mins*60 +  seconds;
time1 = hours2*3600 + mins2*60 +  seconds2;

    //time2 will always be less than time1

    time_diff_secs = time1_secs - time2_secs;
    time_diff_mins = time_diff_secs / 60;
    time_diff_secs = time_diff_secs % 60;
```

this produces this output:

```
Time mayday was issued: 13 Hours 4 Mins 0 Seconds 
Time mayday was recieved: 13 Hours 10 Mins 0 Seconds 
Time between sending and receiving:  6.00Mins
```

which is correct, but when I have two times that are on different days I get this as the result:

```
Time mayday was issued: 23 Hours 0 Mins 0 Seconds 
Time mayday was recieved: 0 Hours 39 Mins 38 Seconds 
Time between sending and receiving: 71581448.00Mins
```

This is obviously incorrect, I am not sure how to progress from here, the actual result should be 40mins, not 71.5million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an underflow. Try this (works regardless of whether the variables are  `signed` or `unsigned`):

```
if (time1_secs < time2_secs) {
    // New day. Add 24 hours:
    time_diff_secs = 24*60*60 + time1_secs - time2_secs;
} else {
    time_diff_secs = time1_secs - time2_secs;
}

time_diff_mins = time_diff_secs / 60;
time_diff_secs = time_diff_secs % 60;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it using the standard C library, the only advantage of this is you do not have to worry about your dates overlapping years, or problems with overlapping month boundaries + leap year nonsense:

```
unsigned int day;
unsigned int month;
unsigned int year;

unsigned int hour;
unsigned int mins;
unsigned int seconds;


time_t conv(void)
{
   time_t retval=0;
   struct tm tm;
   tm.tm_mday=day;
   tm.tm_mon=month -1;
   tm.tm_year=year - 1900;
   tm.tm_hour=hour;
   tm.tm_min=mins;
   tm.tm_sec=seconds;
   tm.tm_isdst=-1;
   retval=mktime(&tm);
   return retval;
}

int main()
{
   time_t start=0;
   time_t end=0;
   time_t diff=0;
   // assign day, month, year ... for date1
   start=conv();
   // assign day, month, year ... for date2
   end=conv();
   if(start>end)
     diff=start - end;
   else
     diff=end - start;
   printf("seconds difference = %ld\n", diff);
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Nice.  If time (YMDHMS) is in _local_ time, this is _the_ way to do it.  If time is UTC, other work is needed.   OP did not stated one or the other, but "mayday" calls imply organizations like the Coast Guard, which uses UTC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a bit too advanced for it worked but i would have been marked down for not fully understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
time_diff_secs = time1_secs - time2_secs;
```

to

```
time_diff_secs = abs(time1_secs - time2_secs) % 86400;
```

This will force it to be the minimum time difference between both times and will work even if you add days, months, etcetera to the `time_diff_secs` calculation.

Comment: just a quick question, why % 86400?

Comment: It's the amount of seconds in a day. 24*60*60 would be less cryptic, but I have the number memorized for some reason!