# C programming - calculate differences of 2 date times

Tags: c, date, datetime

I am trying to use `getDateTime` to calculate the difference between two different time dates: It suppose to be something like this:

Enter date and time `(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss): 2017-03-13 12:00:00 Start: Mon Mar 13 12:00:00 2017`

Enter date and time `(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss): 2017-03-13 12:00:30 End: Mon Mar 13 12:00:30 2017`

Difference: **30** seconds.

This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int dayOfWeek(int d, int m, int y){
// Compute day of week: 0 Sun 1 Mon...6 Sat
  int z;
  if(m<3){
      z=y;
      y=y-1;
  }
  else z=y-2;
  return (23*m/9 + d + z + 4 +
          y/4- y/100 + y/400)%7;
}
    int  getDateTime(struct tm *t){
    int year,month,day,hrs,min,sec;
    printf("Enter date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss): ");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day);
    scanf("%d:%d:%d",&hrs,&min,&sec);
    int x;
    t->tm_year = year - 1900;
    t->tm_mon = month - 1;
    t->tm_mday = day;
    t->tm_hour = hrs;
    t->tm_min = min;
    t->tm_sec = sec;
    t->tm_wday  =  dayOfWeek(day,month,year);

    return ;
}
int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    struct tm Time1 , Time2;
    double x;

     getDateTime(&Time1);
     printf("Start: %s", asctime(&Time1));
     getDateTime(&Time2);
     printf("End: %s", asctime(&Time2));


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I was able to print it in the correct format, but how do I calculate the difference in seconds ? I tried to use difftime but I think I use it wrong. Many thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932909/difference-between-two-dates-in-c does this help you?

Comment: You could use `mktime` or `timegm` to get the seconds since epoch for each date, then calculate their difference.

Comment: Good luck getting time-zones, daylight savings and leap seconds correct, though...

Comment: "I tried to use difftime but I think I use it wrong.". Why don't you show your attempt, and the resulting (incorrect) output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355873/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-on-two-different-days

Answer (score 0):

There's already a function to parse dates, strptime. It's like scanf for dates. It follows the same formatting codes as [strftime](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm) (p for parse, f for format).

You can do it long hand.

```
struct tm date;
strptime( "2017-03-13 12:00:00", "%Y-%m-%s %H:%M:%S", &date );
```

Or use the short hands provided for ISO 8601 dates and times.

```
struct tm date;
strptime( "2017-03-13 12:00:00", "%F %T", &date );
```

That replaces `getDateTime`.

---

Once that's done and you have the dates as `struct tm`, you can convert them to seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) and subtract. Converting to seconds since the epoch, time_t, is done using `mktime`. Then subtract with `difftime`.

```
time_t seconds1 = mktime(&date1);
time_t seconds2 = mktime(&date2);
double timediff = difftime( seconds1, seconds2 );
```

Though, quite honestly, you can also just `seconds1 - seconds2`. `difftime` was added to the standard to allow `time_t` to not be a simple number, but I know of no instance of that.

`mktime` assumes the date is in the local time zone. That doesn't matter for the purposes of diffing two dates in the same time zone.

If it does, there's the non-standard function [`timegm`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/timegm), which is `mktime` but it assumes they're UTC dates. Or you can write your own using the POSIX functions `setenv` and `tzset` to change the time zone temporarily.

```
time_t my_timegm(struct tm *date) {
    // Store the current TZ value.
    char *tz = getenv("TZ");

    // Unset TZ which will cause UTC to be used.
    setenv("TZ", "", 1);
    tzset();

    // Call mktime, now in UTC.
    time_t time = mktime(date);

    // Restore the TZ environment variable (or leave it unset).
    if (tz)
        setenv("TZ", tz, 1);
    else
        unsetenv("TZ");
    tzset();

    return time;
}
```